# RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am constantly getting a runtime error when trying to bind this database to my app.

I have tried different ways to solve this error but I am constantly getting the same runtime error.

```
from datetime import date
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

do as such:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context()
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///database.db'
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='thisisasecretkey'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

using app.app_context() should fix that error